# unable to see out put of any command on hive

Tags: hiveql

I am not able to view my query result when I do query on hive shell(even its executing successfully).

when I do "show tables;" its displaying list of tables as below
hive> show tables;
OK
bucketed_users
logs
managed_table
records
student
students
tweets
user

but when I do any query its executing but its not displaying output
EG:
hive> select * from students;
OK
Time taken: 0.164 seconds

Is there any settings required to print output on my console or is there any issues with my hive shell. please help on this....

Comment: what is the ouput of 'describe formatted students;' and also check whether hdfs://NN:port/user/hive/warehouse/students having anything inside it ??

Answer (score 0):

I created the table one day before I ran the select query. I discovered that there is no data in the `students` table. I don't know how the data got lost.

When I dropped and recreated the "Students" table, I was able to run all queries on it fine.